# Printing items from Class based List

Tags: c#, list, class, printing, textbox

I have a List based on my class:

```
class Vara
{
    public int streckKod { get; set; }
    public string artNamn { get; set; }
}
```

and the list looks like this:

```
List<Vara> minaVaror = new List<Vara>();
```

I'm adding to the list by this line:

```
minaVaror.Add(new Vara() {streckKod = inputBox1, artNamn = textBox2.Text });
```

But my problem is when I want to print an item from the lest to a textbox, let's say texBox3,

How can I print an item from the list as every item now contains 2 variables, and also would I be able to only print one of the 2 variables? Say if I just wanted to print the arNamn variable.

Comment: `textBox.Text = minaVaror[0].srtNamn` ?

Comment: You have to be more explicit about the item you want to select in your "print"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = minaVaror[0].artNamn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the text like this -

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = minaVaror[0].artNamn;
```

---

Or more specifically if you don't want to update the text everywhere, you can `override ToString()` method in your class and `return variable` which you want to print -

```
class Vara
{
    public int streckKod { get; set; }
    public string artNamn { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
       return artNamn;
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about changing variable name everywhere in case you want to replace it with other variable in future. Only need to update in `ToString()` method.

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = minaVaror[0];
```